# Unable to iterate over more than four JSON objects

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-mobile

I'm going through a bunch of JSON objects, first of all creating a list of the 'names' then using the name to search through the JSON file and grab various objects out from underneath the 'name'd object.

The problem I'm having is that when there's more than four objects in the JSON file, the script is falling over quite badly (browser is hanging then giving me a 'Warning: Unresponsive script' error).

Accessing the first four objects is fine, but clicking on the link generated to go to the fifth is when it all goes wrong.

Example JSON is as follows…

```
{"glass":[
  {
     "name":"Drink Name 1",
     "ingredients":{
        "liquids":["Gin", "Tonic"],
        "amounts":[60, 180],
        "colours":["ffffff", "51c98c"],
        "garnish":["Cucumber slice"],
        "ice":["cubes"]
     },
     "method":["Add plenty of ice into glass", "Pour gin over ice", "Top up with tonic", "Stir"],
     "finished":["FAFFFE"]
  },
  {
     "name":"Drink Name 2",
     "ingredients":{
        "liquids":["Gin", "Tonic"],
        "amounts":[60, 180],
        "colours":["ffffff", "51c98c"],
        "garnish":["Cucumber slice"],
        "ice":["cubes"]
     },
     "method":["Add plenty of ice into glass", "Pour gin over ice", "Top up with tonic", "Stir"],
     "finished":["FAFFFE"]
  },      
  {
     "name":"Drink Name 3",
     "ingredients":{
        "liquids":["Gin", "Tonic"],
        "amounts":[60, 180],
        "colours":["ffffff", "51c98c"],
        "garnish":["Cucumber slice"],
        "ice":["cubes"]
     },
     "method":["Add plenty of ice into glass", "Pour gin over ice", "Top up with tonic", "Stir"],
     "finished":["FAFFFE"]
  },
  {
     "name":"Drink Name 4",
     "ingredients":{
        "liquids":["Gin", "Tonic"],
        "amounts":[60, 180],
        "colours":["ffffff", "51c98c"],
        "garnish":["Cucumber slice"],
        "ice":["cubes"]
     },
     "method":["Add plenty of ice into glass", "Pour gin over ice", "Top up with tonic", "Stir"],
     "finished":["FAFFFE"]
  },
  {
     "name":"Drink Name 5",
     "ingredients":{
        "liquids":["Gin", "Tonic"],
        "amounts":[60, 180],
        "colours":["ffffff", "51c98c"],
        "garnish":["Cucumber slice"],
        "ice":["cubes"]
     },
     "method":["Add plenty of ice into glass", "Pour gin over ice", "Top up with tonic", "Stir"],
     "finished":["FAFFFE"]
  }
]
}
```

And my code (well part of it) is currently looking like this…

```
//Get the JSON list and search through it for a match to the recipe name
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
cache:false;
      for (var i=0;i<data.glass.length;i++){
      var glass = data.glass[i]

      //Matching the recipe to the cocktail name
      if (glass.name == recipe){


       // Saving the liquids array as a variable
      liquidIng = (data.glass[i].ingredients.liquids)
      console.log(liquidIng);

      //Saving the amounts as a variable
      liquidAmounts = (data.glass[i].ingredients.amounts)
      var total = 0
           for (var i = 0; i < liquidAmounts.length; i++) {
            total += parseInt(liquidAmounts[i]);
            }

      //Divide the total by 100 to get onePercent
      var onePercent
      onePercent = total /100;

      //Write and multiply the amounts by the onePercent
      var outputAmounts="<div style=\"height:100%\">";
      for (var i in liquidAmounts) {
      outputAmounts+="<div style=\"height:" + liquidAmounts[i] / onePercent + "%; background-color:#" + glass.ingredients.colours[i] + "\">" + glass.ingredients.liquids[i] + "</div>";
      }
      outputAmounts+="</div>";

      document.getElementById("ingredientsAmounts").innerHTML=outputAmounts;        


      //Write the list of ingredients
      var outputIngredients="<ul>";
      for (var i in liquidIng) {
      outputIngredients+="<li>" + glass.ingredients.liquids[i] + "</li>";
      }
      outputIngredients+="</ul>";
      outputIngredients+="<p>" + glass.ingredients.garnish[0] + "</p>";

      document.getElementById("ingredientsList").innerHTML=outputIngredients;

      //Writing the Method
      var outputMethod="<ul>";
      for (var i in glass.method) {
      outputMethod+="<li>" + glass.method[i] + "</li>";
      }
      outputMethod+="</ul>";

      document.getElementById("methodList").innerHTML=outputMethod;

      }//Matching cocktail ends
      }//Get Recipe function ends
});
```

The script outputs the HTML that it's supposed to but not before it's had a good six second think about it. Then it all grinds to a halt.

The closest thing I can understand to be a debugging message is for the line that reads…

```
 var glass = data.glass[i]
```

I'm very new to JQuery so please try to overlook my ignorance – I'm truly stumped. Any help would be massively appreciated. (Also, apologise for posting reams of JSON code)

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: You are re-using the variable `i` for different things within the same loop. That's why your code fails.

Comment: @Tomalak I think you've got it – I'm just trying to separate the loops out into different functions and it seems to be doing the trick. Thanks for your comment though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the updated code, seems you were using the inner for loops incorrectly.. I removed the if condition to check for the receipe, but u can put it back in..

Atleast now your code would not get stuck in the loop. But you might still need to fix the values you want to display, as im not sure much about the logic.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.glass.length; i++) {
      var glass = data.glass[i];

       // Saving the liquids array as a variable
      liquidIng = (data.glass[i].ingredients.liquids);
      console.log("Liquid: " + liquidIng);

      //Saving the amounts as a variable
      liquidAmounts = (data.glass[i].ingredients.amounts)
      var total = 0

      for (var j = 0; j < liquidAmounts.length; j++) {
            total += parseInt(liquidAmounts[j]);
      }

      //Divide the total by 100 to get onePercent
      var onePercent
      onePercent = total /100;

      //Write and multiply the amounts by the onePercent
      var outputAmounts="<div style=\"height:100%\">";
      for (var p in liquidAmounts) {
          outputAmounts+="<div style=\"height:" + p / onePercent + "%; background-color:#" + glass.ingredients.colours[i] + "\">" + glass.ingredients.liquids[i] + "</div>";
      }
      outputAmounts+="</div>";

      document.getElementById("ingredientsAmounts").innerHTML=outputAmounts;        


      //Write the list of ingredients
      var outputIngredients="<ul>";
      for (var p in liquidIng) {
          outputIngredients+="<li>" + p + "</li>";
      }
      outputIngredients+="</ul>";
      outputIngredients+="<p>" + glass.ingredients.garnish[0] + "</p>";

      document.getElementById("ingredientsList").innerHTML=outputIngredients;

      //Writing the Method
      var outputMethod="<ul>";
      for (var p in glass.method) {
          outputMethod+="<li>" + p + "</li>";
      }
      outputMethod+="</ul>";

      document.getElementById("methodList").innerHTML=outputMethod;


}//Get Recipe function ends
```

Comment: Thanks for this @Dilberted it was the loops that were going crazy. Is there something you think I've got wrong with the logic (creating the percentages)? I seem to be getting the right outputs but it wouldn't surprise me if there was a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer to your question, but I can suggest a few things to check and useful tricks.

- First, if you have not done so already, and assuming that your actual data is not identical as the example is, make sure that it's actually a case of location in list rather than content.  Shuffle the data order around  and check whether or not it still dies on #5
- Next, add debug statements - single line commands that will be easy to perceive (outputting to screen is often helpful for this, but may be less so in your case.  If there is anything you can do that will provide output that you can perceive prior to the crash, then you can use that to track down what line exactly is causing the problem, and may be able to use it to acquire information about the state immediately prior to the crash - both quite useful.  If nothing else, you should be able to artificially terminate the function early, outputting data to the html somewhere - it'll make tracking the specific spot down a bit more annoying, since you'll only be able to make one check per run, but it should still help a fair bit.
- Additionally, try on different browsers/computers, if it is relatively easy to do so.  If it's a browser-specific bug, you may well be able to use that to find other people who have had the same problem and/or identify more closely what the issue is.

Comment: I've tried various orders of the data so it's definitely not a content thing. Likewise, it manages to knacker up every browser I have. Will try commenting out around where I suspect the problem lies. Valuable tips – thanks, @Ben-Barden.

Comment: Glad to be of what assistance I can.  If you come up with any further information from doing so, but still can't figure out the answer, by all means edit it into your question and I'll see what I can do to help further.

Answer (score 0):

As @Tomalak noticed, I was reusing the 'i' variable multiple times within the same function. I've picked it all apart and separated the steps across different functions which seems to have done the trick.

Thanks for you comments and help though guys. As ever it's hugely appreciated.